# Help me identify this resistor

Tags: resistors, identification, surface-mount

I am trying to troubleshoot a faulty camcorder PCB and stumbled upon this resistor(?) that is right near the DC jack.

The resistance between it is 0 Ohms.

What is this component? I couldn't find anything searching for this value on the internet.

[image: Unknown SMD]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Get the service manual. The resistor looks ok, apart from measuring it out of circuit, I’d be looking elsewhere. Resistors rarely fail short circuit - open circuit,yes.

Comment: @Kartman But is this in fact a resistor? According to the SMD standard "68" should be 68Ohms, but it's zero.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a current shunt - 68 milliohms. That's what the "M" stands for. It's used to measure the current drawn by the circuit which also explains its large size (and therefore high power rating).

The resistor is perfectly fine if you measure a short-circuit across it.

Comment: I was thinking to myself "Is this literally a M or some kind of symbol?" Now it makes sense. Thank you, learned something new!